# Generating random SVG arrow shapes

Tags: javascript, svg, vector-graphics

So I have a task, which intends to generate random SVG images of curved entangled arrows.

Here are few examples of the expected output:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIDu3.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX6YB.png)

[Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P04Ao.png)

There are few main requirements:

1. Arrow shape shouldn't have any sharp curves, for example like [this](https://monosnap.com/file/CCtooMfjMf98K3j9VdppmpySHpdxlx)
2. Arrowhead should always watch upwards at the end or at least tend to do so
3. Shape starts on the left side of canvas and ends up in the right part
4. There should be a random number (from 1 to 5) [entanglements](https://monosnap.com/file/a9AybI0OYzw20eXooCjlcPZeW9LmzX)

What would be the best approach for this given that my knowledge of geometry is very basic?
Is it even possible to generate random shapes with such requirements?

Comment: For this I would use the S command (smooth cubic curve-to command).  This command will take 2 pairs of values for 2 control points. Make both control points have the same y value. Make the second control point x smaller than the x of the first control point. For 3 entanglements use 3 S commands where the first control point x of each command are equally distributed, while the y has a random value around a central line